# Upgrading from JACKSON 1.9->2.1 outputting a lot of debug logs

Tags: java, debugging, logging, jackson, wadl

Recently upgraded our large project from jackson 1.9 to 2.1. Everything is working fine, except when you run some of the tests, lots of debug code is outputted in console. This is breaking a logger test that requires 0 debug output. I've had a look around and can't seem to find a solution or anyone else who's had a similar issue.

First few lines:

[DEBUG] Property com.sun.xml.internal.bind.XmlAccessorFactoryis not active.  Using JAXB's implementation

[DEBUG] Using optimized Accessor for protected java.util.List com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Request.doc

[DEBUG] Using optimized Accessor for protected java.util.List com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Doc.content

[DEBUG] Using optimized Accessor for protected java.lang.String com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Doc.title

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: I've done searches for: 'xmlaccessorfactory', 'jaxb', 'accessor', 'wadl' and 'research' in our project. No matches for any of these words.

Comment: Can you not just set the log level of the logger(s) in question to INFO?

Comment: The test that is breaking, tests that at an INFO level, the number of DEBUG logs is 0. Because these [DEBUG] lines are output on almost every runtime, the count is over 0, and the test therefore breaks. I need a way of either suppressing these specific logs specifically, fixing the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was in a logback.xml file, that defines our logging levels. Upgraded version of jackson uses a different package location for com.sun.xml, so had to change:

```
<logger name="com.sun.xml.bind" level="${log.level:-info}" />
```

to:

```
<logger name="com.sun.xml.internal.bind" level="${log.level:-info}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something GlassFish or Jersey might be producing. Jackson does not output such debug information; it does not use logger or print anything in System.err or System.out.